# ¿Cómo detectar el evento o deshabilitar el botón atrás del navegador con AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Me gustaría deshabilitar el botón de atrás del navegador o detectar ese evento y poder mostrar una alerta.

Comment: porque quieres deshabilitarlo? alguna funcionalidad en particular?

Comment: Deshabilitarlo o mostrar una alerta para decirle al usuario que si esta seguro de devolverse y perder lo que tiene actualmente en la vista

Comment: ¿Algo como esto? [Detect history back using angular](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15813850/detect-history-back-using-angular)

Comment: Gracias, si es parte de la solución @CésarBustíos

Answer (score 7):

Lo puedes hacer directo con javascript no necesariamente utilizando angularjs puedes utilizar lo siguiente espero y te sirva

```
function deshabilitaRetroceso(){
    window.location.hash="no-back-button";
    window.location.hash="Again-No-back-button" //chrome
    window.onhashchange=function(){window.location.hash="no-back-button";}
}
```

Y en el body del documento html mandas llamar la función

```
<html>
    <head>....</head>
    <body onload="deshabilitaRetroceso()">.....</body>
</html>
```

Espero y te sirva

Answer (score 3):

Con esto previenes incluso que salgan de la actual página en la que están, por si la cierran.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onbeforeunload = function() {
      return "¿Estás seguro que deseas salir de la actual página?"
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Eso la verdad no funciona