# ¿Cómo mostrar mensaje al presionar botón atrás del navegador?

Tags: javascript

necesito mostrar un mensaje al presionar el botón atrás del navegador, buscando por internet encontré una función para deshabilitar el botón atrás del navegados y quisiera añadir un mensaje al presionar dicho botón, sera posible?

```
function deshabilitaRetroceso(){
window.location.hash="no-back-button";
window.location.hash="Again-No-back-button" //chrome
window.onhashchange=function(){window.location.hash="no-back-button";}
```

}

Comment: Necesitas capturar el evento. Hay otra pregunta al respecto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/2092/cómo-detectar-el-evento-o-deshabilitar-el-botón-atrás-del-navegador-con-angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para realizar el mensaje debes realizar una función con el mensaje que tu quieras al interior de un alert:

```
function mensaje{
window.location.hash=alert("Acción realizada");}
```

en caso de necesitar mas información:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

Comment: ¿En que parte de la pagina se coloca ese código?